# Managing resources via compilation flags

Tags: .net, vb.net

Any idea how i can do that ?

Now days it is done in `Resources.Designer.vb` we have there following lines:

```
Friend ReadOnly Property ResourceManager() As Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager
            Get
                   If Object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, Nothing) Then
                        #If WizardVersion Then
                            Dim temp As Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager = New Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager("Wizard.Resources", GetType(Resources).Assembly)
                        #ElseIf CalculatorVersion Then
                            Dim temp As Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager = New Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager("Calculator.Resources", GetType(Resources).Assembly)
                        #ElseIf ViewerVersion Then
                            Dim temp As Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager = New Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager("Viewer.Resources", GetType(Resources).Assembly)
                        #End If
                    resourceMan = temp
                End If
                Return resourceMan
            End Get
        End Property
```

That file is regenerated each time via the compiler and so each time i have to add there those lines by hand.

Can you suggest some another way to do so ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use reflection to overwrite the ResourceManager created by the Resources class :

```
Sub InitResources()
    #If WizardVersion Then
        Dim temp As Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager = New Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager("Wizard.Resources", GetType(Resources).Assembly)
    #ElseIf CalculatorVersion Then
        Dim temp As Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager = New Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager("Calculator.Resources", GetType(Resources).Assembly)
    #ElseIf ViewerVersion Then
        Dim temp As Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager = New Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager("Viewer.Resources", GetType(Resources).Assembly)
    #End If

    Dim resManField As System.Reflection.FieldInfo = GetType(My.Resources.Resources).GetField("resourceMan", Reflection.BindingFlags.Static Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    resManField.SetValue(Nothing, temp)

End Sub
```

That's not very elegant, but it should work...

Comment: Call it when your program starts, before you need any resources. In the Sub Main for instance

Comment: It doesn't compile  i get on GetType(Resources).Assembly ->  Resources type expected

Comment: I copied/pasted this part from your code... replace `GetType(Resources)` with `GetType(My.Resources.Resources)`

Comment: Ok this compiled but i got a lot of exceptions , when i run it.
I have put it this code as early as i could .

Comment: Exception.InnerException  The error is: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.

Comment: On which line ? and where do you execute this method ? in the Main sub, in your form constructor, somewhere else ?

Comment: I execute it on the first lines of form1.vb. And I am getting the exception when some resource is called .

Comment: "the first lines" doesn't mean anything, since the order of the methods can change... is it in the constructor (Sub New) ? in the Load event ? And by the way, did you just paste the method in your code, or do you actually call it ? put a breakpoint in the method to check that it is called

Comment: I have pasted the code at the first lines of Sub New.I get my error before the constructor of my main file is called.The error happens in file called aplication.designer.vb . I think this file is generated by the compiler.
You can think about better place were i can put this code in .

Comment: Yes, put it in Sub Main. If it doesn't exist, create it, and declare it as your startup object (in project properties)

Comment: Can't it be done without changing the current enter point ?Now it's Form1 i tried to do that there but with no succeed

Comment: No, because if you don't create the Main method yourself, VS creates it for you and you have no control over it. This code has to be executed before anything accesses the resources

Comment: One more question, what code I should call from main that my application will work as before i added the main ?I should call the contractor of form1 class ?

Comment: Yes, you need to call the constructor : Dim f As New Form1() then run the app : Application.Run(f)

Comment: My project is of type windows application. Can i add there main ? I added there main like you said but i couldn't see it in the start from menu.

Comment: Just create a new module and add a method with the following signature : `Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)`

Comment: Still problem . Look on the new message i put in the post

Answer (score 1):

You could run a batch file that copies (and overrides the old file) the files into the proper place on a pre-build action. You could take a flag in as a parameter of the batch.